# Mock fetch in Jest tests throwing “invalid json response” and “Unhandled promise rejection” errors

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, create-react-app, redux-saga

I’m trying to do unit tests for some of my redux-saga generators and am getting a couple of errors I’m not sure how to resolve. I’m using `create-react-app`, so my testing suite is Jest and Enzyme.

A basic example:

**Setup:** `src/setupTests.js`

```
import 'jest-enzyme'
import { configure } from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

global.fetch = require('jest-fetch-mock')

configure({
    adapter: new Adapter(),
    automock: false,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        '<rootDir>/src/**/*.js',
        '!<rootDir>/src/**/*.stories.js',
        '!<rootDir>/node_modules/',
        '!<rootDir>/src/index.js',
    ],
    coverageThreshold: {
        global: {
            branches: 90,
            functions: 90,
            lines: 90,
            statements: 90,
        },
    },
    verbose: true,
})
```

**Saga:** `src/store/sagas/api-saga.js`

```
import { takeEvery, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

import {
    API_ERRORED,
    DATA_LOADED,
    DATA_REQUESTED,
} from '../constants/action-types'

export function* workerSaga() {
    try {
        const payload =
            yield fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
                .then(response => response.json())
        yield put({
            type: DATA_LOADED,
            payload,
        })
    } catch (e) {
        yield put({
            type: API_ERRORED,
            payload: false,
        })
    }
}

export default function* watcherSaga() {
    yield takeEvery(
        DATA_REQUESTED,
        workerSaga,
    )
}
```

**Saga Test:** `src/store/sagas/api-saga.test.js`

```
import { put, takeEvery } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import watcherSaga, { workerSaga } from './api-saga'

import {
    API_ERRORED,
    DATA_LOADED,
    DATA_REQUESTED,
} from '../constants/action-types'

describe('saga workers', () => {
    test('should dispatch action "DATA_LOADED" with result from fetch API',
        () => {
            const articles = 'Some content'
            const mockResponse = {
                articles,
            }
            const generator = workerSaga()

            generator.next()

            expect(generator.next(mockResponse).value)
                .toEqual(
                    put({
                        type: DATA_LOADED,
                        payload: {
                            articles,
                        },
                    })
                )

            expect(generator.next().done).toBeTruthy()
        })
})
```

The errors I’m receiving:

```sh
(node:2009) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at undefined reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
(node:2009) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:2009) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:2009) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at undefined reason: Unexpected end of JSON input
(node:2009) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
```

I thought introducing `jest-fetch-mock` would help resolve some of these issues, but it doesn’t seem so. The tests pass, but these errors persist.

What am I missing?

#### Versions

redux@4.0.4
redux-saga@1.0.5
enzyme@3.10.0
jest@24.7.1

Comment: I suspect your `mockResponse` has invalid json format.

Comment: I suspect your `mockResponse` has invalid json format.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to set up `jest-fetch-mock` to return a value:

Something like:

```
describe('saga workers', () => {
    test('should dispatch action "DATA_LOADED" with result from fetch API',
        () => {
            const articles = 'Some content'
            const mockResponse = {
                articles,
            }
            // configure the mockResponse here:
            fetch.mockResponse(mockResponse);
            const generator = workerSaga()

            generator.next()

            expect(generator.next().value)
                .toEqual(
                    put({
                        type: DATA_LOADED,
                        payload: {
                            articles,
                        },
                    })
                )

            expect(generator.next().done).toBeTruthy()
        })
})
```

See https://github.com/jefflau/jest-fetch-mock#api